# How many plagiarized answers cause a suspension?

Tags: support, plagiarism, account-suspension

How many plagiarized answers can someone post before getting a suspension? Is there an algorithm to count the total answers before suspension or it's determined by the diamond user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is up to the ♦ moderators to decide; there is no automated process for detecting and resolving plagiarism. As described in [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days.

Usually, the first instance of plagiarism will be met by a comment explaining that this is a no-go, and deletion of the answer or editing in attribution. Suspension is reserved for repeat offenders.

Comment: Correct. I do consider suspending on a first offense when there was a combination of issues, like running a sock puppet that used plagiarism. At some point it is clear it wasn’t just a misunderstanding about what is acceptable.